# how to get a specific user details from json api

Tags: javascript, json

can anyone please help with code to get specific user details from json by the name passed, lets say if i enter john it must return all the details of john.  here is my json

```
{
  "results":[
    {
      "gender":"male",
      "name":{
        "title":"mr",
        "first":"john",
        "last":"jordan"
      },
      "location":{
        "street":"3277 green rd",
        "city":"australian capital territory",
        "state":"queensland",
        "postcode":275
      },
      "email":"eugene.jordan@example.com",
      "login":{
        "username":"beautifulbutterfly703",
        "password":"redhot",
        "salt":"tva1i6Oo",
        "md5":"a4231f30aa1fcfe46e4c7c4537a4bf11",
        "sha1":"d6051a921eba285bbeccd95388332f92a50047ce",
        "sha256":"093b0e1b429a105902f91e4be28c9dc12629701924312d63d55cdfd556d54c38"
      },
      "registered":1000882268,
      "dob":537587321,
      "phone":"02-4894-6208",
      "cell":"0477-498-405",
      "id":{
        "name":"TFN",
        "value":"571061435"
      },
      "picture":{
        "large":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/12.jpg",
        "medium":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/12.jpg",
        "thumbnail":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/12.jpg"
      },
      "nat":"AU"
    }
  ],
  "info":{
    "seed":"8eb0b2c2e327a185",
    "results":1,
    "page":1,
    "version":"1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why can't you just use a for loop and check `name.first`?

Comment: This is a broad question. Are you able to search by first name, last name, or both? Do you need an exact match? Are you using a library? Did you even try to do something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter the JSON dataset you have you just filter the array with javascript.

In this example I've added another person to the 'results' object (so there are two user records in the array), and am filtering the JSON data for any entry that has a first name of jane:

```
var item = array[0].results.filter(function (selection){ 
    return selection.name.first === 'jane';
});

console.log(item);
```

[Here is a fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tamak/x23jt84p/79/), let me know if you have any question about how to implement it for your needs.

In the fiddle I have it basically working as a find-as-you-type process.... so if you start entering jan or joh you'll see the matches it finds as you enter characters.

I have it finding partial string matches without case sensitivity, but have included a commented out line that will instead find exact matches (which would mean case sensitive).

Let me know if you have any questions at all, good luck!

Comment: Hi Tamak Thank you so much, that really helped

Comment: Glad I could help.  Please mark it as the correct answer and upvote. Thanks!

Comment: @jack Glad I could help. Please mark it as the correct answer and upvote. Thanks!